# Blazorise Multi-Selection Filter

Tags: blazorise

Has anyone found a way to filter a datagrid by more than one option in blazorise?

Tried using SelectList in a new modal to create a list to filter on, and Checkboxes to create a list to filter on

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5NQQ.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN2kM.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Blazorise DataGrid [Custom Column Filtering example](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/features/filtering) modified to support multiple selected values.

```
<DataGrid TItem="Employee"
          Data="@employeeList"
          Filterable
          Responsive>
    <DataGridColumn Field="@nameof(Employee.FirstName)" Caption="Name" Editable="false"></DataGridColumn>
    <DataGridSelectColumn CustomFilter="@OnGenderCustomFilter" Field="@nameof(Employee.Gender)" Caption="Gender" Editable>
        <FilterTemplate>
            <Select TValue="string"
                    SelectedValues="@selectedGenderFilter"
                    SelectedValuesChanged="@(value => { selectedGenderFilter = value; context.TriggerFilterChange(selectedGenderFilter); })"
                    Multiple>
                <SelectItem Value="@("*")">All</SelectItem>
                <SelectItem Value="@("M")">Male</SelectItem>
                <SelectItem Value="@("F")">Female</SelectItem>
                <SelectItem Value="@("D")">Diverse</SelectItem>
            </Select>
        </FilterTemplate>
    </DataGridSelectColumn>
</DataGrid>
@code{
    private List<Employee> employeeList = new() { new() { FirstName = "David", Gender = "M" }, new() { FirstName = "Mladen", Gender = "M" }, new() { FirstName = "John", Gender = "M" }, new() { FirstName = "Ana", Gender = "F" }, new() { FirstName = "Jessica", Gender = "F" } };

    private IReadOnlyList<string> selectedGenderFilter;

    private bool OnGenderCustomFilter(object itemValue, object searchValue)
    {
        if (searchValue is IReadOnlyList<string> genderFilter)
        {
            return genderFilter.Contains("*") || genderFilter.Contains(itemValue?.ToString());
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```